# Альтернатива window.pageYoffset и window.scrollY в Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4

Насколько мне известно, бегунок находится вне DOM, поэтому его можно прочитать только через 2 вышеуказанных метода.

Или я ошибаюсь и есть у Angular свои примочки на этот случай?

Comment: Не знаю что вы подразумеваете под примочками, но вам никто не запрещает в компоненте в любой момент использовать `window.pageYoffset`. Если он нужен в шаблоне - сделайте например  функцию которая его возвращает и используйте ее `<div>{{getYoffset()}}</div>`